# Core-input / Paper-input datalist autocomplete

Tags: dart, polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I'm trying to get my paper-input to have autocompletion with the html5 tag datalist.

this is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
<paper-input id="pi" list="dl"></paper-input>
<datalist id="dl">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>abcd</option>
    <option>bcd</option>
    <option>bcde</option>
</datalist>
```

I have also tried to go with chrome inspector and add a `list` attribute to the `<input>` inside the shadow root of the paper-input, but it's not working.

Is it supposed to work at all?

Comment: I don't know the answer to you question but the `core-input` and with it the paper-input are about to change notably with the next update. They are changed to extend `input-element` and in addition only use a wrapper element for material-design effects. With this change it `core-input` and `paper-input` will have the same functionality and behavior like the DOM input element.

Comment: Is this available on pub servers? (in a possible early version)

Comment: core-elements and paper-elements packages are all still early versions ;-). You just have to check the versions tab of the package on pub.dartlang.org. Package versions where the build version is not starting with a `-` are fetched automatically others need a specific dependency in `pubspec.yaml` to get fetched. I don't know if this change is already included in the JavaScript version of the elements. The docs don't reflect this change yet.

Comment: When you say you don't know if the change is included in the JS version, does that mean if I create an element by dart code instead of markup/html import, the version of the code maybe be different?

Comment: No, this is not what it means. The Dart version of the elements are automatically generated wrappers added to the JavaScript version of the elements. When a new release of the Dart version is published it can't contain features/changes that are not yet included in the JavaScript version of the elements (this is the point I tried to make).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738342/are-there-any-built-in-auto-complete-input-components-for-polymer-1-0/