# Are there any built in auto-complete input components for Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've been muddling around with Polymer 1.0 since its release, and I've hit a use case where a select list just won't be sufficient (too many options to select from).  What I really need is an autocomplete textbox.

Is there one built-in or planned in the paper or iron Polymer controls?  Or should I be looking at autocomplete solutions from other frameworks?  So far, I've been able to keep my app light-weight, and I'd prefer to avoid other frameworks if I can help it.

Thanks,

Ryan

**Edit:** The best place I've seen to bring up a first-party developed autocomplete is on the PolymerElements/paper-elements repo on GitHub. I'd discuss at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/issues/26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've settled on using HTML5 datalists in conjunction with a modified `<paper-input>` control (I've submitted a pull request to the Github repo to merge those changes back into the master branch).  All those changes do is persist the `list` attribute to the inner `<iron-input>` control so that it can utilize an HTML5 datalist.

Definitely not ideal, but, in the short-term, it'll function as a placeholder in place of a real typeahead control.

I also built a quick custom validator that iterates over the same Array collection as what I use in my datalist so that the `<paper-input>` control knows if the current value is a selectable (valid) value or not.

**Edit:** The best place I've seen to bring up a first-party developed autocomplete is on the PolymerElements/paper-elements repo on GitHub.  I'd discuss at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/issues/26.

Comment: I can only find this fork https://github.com/RNCRyan/paper-input/commit/c880ae9594ff7b1b0e3397f7e579979797fd0e6f. But it only allows list (which is implemented in 1.0.6)

Comment: Yep, I did a pull request to get the "list" attribute on the core paper-input GitHub project.  "list" is an attribute on the github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input project as of 1.0.5 or 1.0.6.

Answer (score 3):

[Vaadin's combo box](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-combo-box) looks pretty solid:

[image: Vaadin combo box]

There is also [Ellipticaljs's Paper Autocomplete](http://ellipticaljs.github.io/paper-autocomplete/), with a possible alternative [md-autocomplete](https://github.com/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/issues/1#issuecomment-191054609) in the works.

[image: paper-autocomplete]

You can find more autocomplete elements by searching at http://customelements.io.