# polymer paper-input html datalist autocomplete/suggestions list

Tags: autocomplete, polymer, element, datalist

so i'm using a simple autocomplete method in polymer with

```
<paper-input autocomplete="on" name="stuff" list="stuffs"></paper-input>
```

with a simple list of items
(tried both **select** and **template** elements to do this)

```
    <datalist id="stuffs">
        <option value="blah blah"/>
            .
            .
            .
    </datalist>
```

thing is, i wanna figure out a way to access the dynamic dropdown list of suggestions that appears during typing.
is there actually a way for this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by accessing it? What kinda behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: like printing it on a different area instead of the dropdown form it currently has

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any built in auto-complete input components for Polymer 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738342/are-there-any-built-in-auto-complete-input-components-for-polymer-1-0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your best bet then is to not use `datalist`.

Here's an example of a component I wrote for my own use:

```
<dom-module id="paper-autocomplete">
    <style>
    iron-collapse {
        box-shadow: 6px;
    }

    paper-button {
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    </style>
    <template>
        <paper-input-container>
            <label>{{label}}</label>
            <content select=".content"></content>
            <input id="searchBox" class="paper-input-input" is="iron-input" bind-value="{{searchValue::input}}"></input>
        </paper-input-container>
        <iron-collapse id="collapse">
            <paper-material>
                <div>
                    <template id="resultList" is="dom-repeat" items="{{choices}}" filter="_listFilter">
                        <paper-item>
                            <paper-button on-tap="_selectItem">{{item.name}}</paper-button>
                        </paper-item>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </paper-material>
        </iron-collapse>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
    Polymer({
        is: "paper-autocomplete",
        properties: {
            choices: Array,
            label: String,
            value: {
                type: Object,
            },
            searchValue: {
                type: String,
                value: '',
                observer: "_valueChanged"
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.$.resultList.render()
        },
        _valueChanged: function(e) {
            var collapse = this.$.collapse
            if (e != '' && !collapse.opened) {
                this.$.resultList.render()
                collapse.toggle()
            } else
            if (e == '' && collapse.opened) {
                collapse.toggle()
            }
        },
        _listFilter: function(item) {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(
                this.searchValue.toLowerCase()
            )
        },
        _selectItem: function(event) {
            var collapse = this.$.collapse;
            this.set('searchValue', event.model.item.name)
            this.set('value', event.model.item)
            collapse.toggle()
        }
    })
})()
</script>
```

`_valueChanged` observes changes to `searchValue` on input and toggles the collapse. `_listFilter` filters the items bound to `dom-repeat` based on `searchValue`.

The `#resultList` or `#collapse` element could be placed elsewhere for your own purposes.

### edit

I should point out that `choices` here is an Array of Objects each of which has a name attribute which is how they are filtered. It could easily be altered to filter on a Array of Strings depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way of importing the PolymerElement components so they actually work.

Comment: These goodies should be imported (with paths suitable to your set up) before:
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">     
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">     
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-container.html">

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a ready made Polymer element, I suggest looking at  https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-combo-box